# Oracle Update with Joins

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I'm trying to convert few MS Access Queries into Oracle. Following is one of the query from MS Access.

```
    UPDATE [RESULT] INNER JOIN [MASTER]
      ON  ([RESULT].[LAST_NAME] = [MASTER].[LAST_NAME]) 
      AND ([RESULT].[FIRST_NAME] = [MASTER].[FIRST_NAME]) 
      AND ([RESULT].[DOCUMENT_NUMBER] = [MASTER].[DOCUMENT_NUMBER]) 
      AND ([RESULT].[BATCH_ID] = [MASTER].[LEAD_ID]) 
    SET [MASTER].[CLOSURE_REASON] = "Closed For Name and Document Number Match", 
        [MASTER].[RESULT_ID] = [RESULT].[ID], 
        [MASTER].[RESULT_PID] = [RESULT].[PID]
    WHERE (([MASTER].[CLOSURE_REASON] Is Null) 
      AND  ([MASTER].[REC_CODE] = "A1") 
      AND  ([RESULT].[EVENT_DATE] = [MASTER].[EVENT_DATE]) 
      AND  ([RESULT].[EVENT_TYPE] = "Open")
      AND  ([MASTER].[DOCUMENT_NUMBER] Is Not Null)
      AND  ([MASTER].[DOCUMENT_NUMBER)]  "null"));
```

First I received ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table Error. I followed different examples (including MERGE) from your site and modified my original query. Now, I receive ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables Error.

Most of the examples showed only one join between the tables but I have to make more joins based on my requirements.

Any help translating this query in to Oracle would be Great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should be equivalent.

```
UPDATE master m
   SET closure_reason = 'Closed For Name and Document Number Match',
       (result_id, result_pid) = (SELECT r.id, r.pid
                                    FROM result r
                                   WHERE m.last_name       = r.last_name
                                     AND m.first_name      = r.first_name
                                     AND m.lead_id         = r.batch_id
                                     AND m.document_number = r.document_number
                                     AND m.event_date      = r.event_date
                                     AND r.event_type      = 'Open')
 WHERE m.closure_reason IS NULL
   AND m.rec_code = 'A1'
   AND m.document_number IS NOT NULL
   AND m.document_number != 'null'
   AND EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM result r
                WHERE m.last_name       = r.last_name
                  AND m.first_name      = r.first_name
                  AND m.lead_id         = r.batch_id
                  AND m.document_number = r.document_number
                  AND m.event_date      = r.event_date
                  AND r.event_type      = 'Open' )
```

Obviously, however, this isn't tested.  If you could post the DDL to create your tables, the DML to insert a few rows, and show the expected result, we could test our code and would likely be able to give you more accurate answers.